# Event of probability zero in a countable sample space and independence - is this possible?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Is it possible for a non-null event $A$ of zero probability to  occur in the context of a countable (countably finite or infinite) sample space?

Further - my motivation for the question is in context of independent events. Suppose for a countable sample space, we have $P(A) = 0$ and $0<P(B)<1$. Then does it follow that $P(A \cap B) = 0$ and hence we can say that $A$ and $B$ are independent?

How does this change if we drop the assumption that the sample space is countable?

Comment: Yes, $\Pr(A\cap B)\leq \Pr(A)$ in all contexts, and in particular when $\Pr(A)=0$ that will imply that $0\leq \Pr(A\cap B)\leq \Pr(A)=0$ and so $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$.  Yes, you can have probability zero events in countable sample spaces including finite sample spaces.  There is no requirement that says otherwise.

Comment: It is *common* to only include in the sample space outcomes and events in the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the probability measure, but there is no requirement to do so.  When talking about the flipping of a fair coin, we could have had the outcomes as $\{H,T,\text{banana}\}$ with $\Pr(H)=\Pr(T)=0.5$ and $\Pr(\text{banana})=0$

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. @JMoravitz

Comment: From a mathematics perspective you already got it right, and JMoravitz confims that in a very good and clear way. However I feel that maybe there is something else underlying your question. You conclude (rightly) that once $Pr(A) = 0$ we have that $A$ is independent from $B$ regardless of what $B$ is. We might even take $B = A$ or something else where from a 'common sense' perspective it is obvious that $A$ and $B$ are *not* independent. So what (I think) underlies or even prompted the question is that in the presence of probability $0$ events, the relation between... (ctd in next comment)

Comment: ...that in the presense of probability $0$ events the relation between the mathematical definiton of independence and the real world notion/intuition of independence this mathematical definition was supposed to capture/model breaks down. (Ctd in next comment)

Comment: Now if this is what you are worried about (is that really true? can we fix it? do we need to fix it?) then I think the somewhat reassuring answer is: yes it is true BUT in real life you will never notice this breakdown, because probability $0$ events are (pretty much by definition) events that you will never encounter in real life. (I believe this is also implicit in JM's banana-example). So yes, the relation between reality and its mathematical model breaks down, but only in cases that don't (or are not expected to) occur in reality and so there is no reason to worry.